# Create a Partition Table in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning, postgresql-10

I'm trying to find an example to create a partition table.
I have some tables with many tuples and I can classify them according to a value of one column, but, I just find examples using range and date (my column is a varchar and, in other table, is a int/foreign key).
I'm trying to speed my SELECT with this technique.

Here one of my CREATE tables (column Source will be used to partition this table):

```
CREATE TABLE tb_hit_source (
Hit_SourceId bigserial NOT NULL,
Source varchar(50) NOT NULL,
UniqueId varchar(50) NOT NULL,
tb_hit_HitId int8 NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT tb_hit_source_ak_1 UNIQUE (Source, tb_hit_HitId, UniqueId) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE,
CONSTRAINT tb_hit_source_pk PRIMARY KEY (Hit_SourceId)
);
CREATE INDEX tb_hit_source_idx_1 on tb_hit_source (Source ASC);
CREATE INDEX tb_hit_source_idx_2 on tb_hit_source (tb_hit_HitId ASC);
ALTER TABLE tb_hit_source ALTER COLUMN Hit_SourceId SET DEFAULT nextval('"HitSourceId_seq_tb_hit_source"');;
```

Comment: how will source be used to partition the table?

Comment: Partitioning the table only speeds up sequential scans.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I already see the manual, but, in my question, I said that I don't find examples without range or date

Comment: @Jasen Source, in this table, indicates where obtains the data of this tuple. I have a limited list of sources. This table will have like of 4 millions of tuples. From each source, I have about 500.000 tuples (except 1 source that have about 1.7 milions of tuples).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I don't have how to use index in partitioned tables?

Comment: varchar(50) is up-to 200 octets. postgresql table-names are limited to 64 octets... `name` might be a better type to use for this column?  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-character.html

Comment: not deferrable implies initially immediate.

Comment: The question is: why do you think you need to partition that table? What is the problem you are trying to solve with that? Maybe filtered indexes (`create index ... where source = 'foo'`) are a better choice here if you want to improve query performance. Partitioning is not the silver bullet that magically makes everything faster

Comment: @WandréVeloso Indexing partitioned tables is the same as on non-partitioned ones, except that you have to Index each partition.

Answer (score 6):

to create the table do.

```
CREATE TABLE tb_hit_source (
Hit_SourceId bigserial NOT NULL,
Source varchar(50) NOT NULL,
UniqueId varchar(50) NOT NULL,
tb_hit_HitId int8 NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT tb_hit_source_ak_1 
    UNIQUE (Source, tb_hit_HitId, UniqueId) NOT DEFERRABLE,
CONSTRAINT tb_hit_source_pk PRIMARY KEY (Hit_SourceId)
PARTITION BY RANGE (Source);
```

then to create the partitions use the same value at each end of the range to force a single value partition.

```
CREATE TABLE tb_hit_source_a PARTITION OF tb_hit_source
    FOR VALUES FROM ('a') TO ('a');
```

etc.

podtgresql 11 offers `PARTITION BY LIST (source)` allowing the partitions to be declared more simply.

```
CREATE TABLE tb_hit_source_a PARTITION OF tb_hit_source
    FOR VALUES IN ('a');
```

Comment: PostgreSQL 11? Are you talking about beta release?

Answer (score 0):

to create the partitions do

```
create table part_a (check source='part_a' )inherits (tb_hit_source);
create table part_a (check source='part_b' )inherits (tb_hit_source);
```

etc.

but if there are going to be many partitions it will probably be more convenient to put them in a separate schema.

```
create schema hit_source_parts;
create table hit_source_parts.a (check(source='a'))inherits (tb_hit_source);
create table hit_source_parts.b (check(source='b'))inherits (tb_hit_source);
```

etc.

Any partitions you make will also need the aproptiate indexes.

unique constraints won't work across partitions this is one reaon why most uses of partitioning partition on one of the unique colums,  by fragmenting this way uniqueness in each partition also enforces global uniqueness.

Comment: The question is tagged with `postgresql-10` so declarative partitioning should be preferred over inheritance